# Delete a directory after untar a file

Tags: java, file, tar, delete-file

I have a .tar.gz file and I want to untar that same file.

To do that I have this function in java:

```
private void unTarFile(String tarFile, File destFile) {
    TarArchiveInputStream tis = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(tarFile);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        // .gz
        gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
        // .tar.gz
        tis = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzipInputStream);
        TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = null;
        while ((tarEntry = tis.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println(" tar entry- " + tarEntry.getName());
            if (tarEntry.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                // In case entry is for file ensure parent directory is in place
                // and write file content to Output Stream
                File outputFile = new File(destFile + File.separator + tarEntry.getName());
                outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                IOUtils.copy(tis, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error while untarring a file- " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (bis != null) {
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (gzipInputStream != null) {
            try {
                gzipInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (tis != null) {
            try {
                tis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works and I can untar my .tar.gz successfully.
I can edit the files of the untarred directory to, but when I try to delete my directory I cant:

[image]

Did I forgot to close something?

Comment: Yes, you have created `FileInputStream` object as `fis` but you have never closed it. And not only File Input Stream you have also use the  `GZIPInputStream` but you have never closed it.

Comment: I edited the question with the sugestions you made but still didnt work @DushyantTankariya

Comment: But I cant close the outputFile, there is no method for it, updated the question with my method, think I close all of it but the error still appears. Maybe is the order of close?@DushyantTankariya